# Envio de e-mail com NodeJS e nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Entendo que existem algumas postagens sobre como enviar email usando NodeJS e nodemailer, porém após muitas tentativas ainda continuo recebendo a falha response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted ao tentar enviar e-mail.

Verifiquei várias vezes login e senha, configurei para que o Google permita aplicativos menos seguro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta falha pode ser alguma linha de código que ainda não achei.

--> email.js

```
module.exports = {
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    user: 'roberto.r.vieiram@gmail.com',
    pass: 'minha senha',
};

const SMTP_CONFIG = require('../config/email');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                        host: SMTP_CONFIG.host,
                        port: SMTP_CONFIG.port,
                        secure: false,
                        auth: {
                            user: SMTP_CONFIG.user,
                            pass: SMTP_CONFIG.pass
                        },
                        tls: {
                            rejectUnauthorized: false,
                        }
                    });

                    var welcome = {
                        from: SMTP_CONFIG.user,
                        to: 'roberto.r.vieiram@gmail.com',
                        subject: 'Teste de e-mail',
                        html: '<h1>Teste envio de e-mail</h1>'
                    };

                    transporter.sendMail(welcome, function (err, info) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('Email enviado: ' + info.response);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          service: 'gmail',
          auth: {
            user: 'email@gmail.com',
            pass: 'senha',
            port: 587,
            secure: true,
          }
        });
    
    const mailOptions = {
          from: 'Meu nome <email@gmail.com>',
          to: 'destinatario <dest@gmail.com>'
          subject: 'assunto',
          html: '<h5>Obrigada por visitar</h5>'
        };
    
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
          if (erro) {
            console.log('Erro ao enviar email');
            return reject(erro);
          }
          return resolve({ success: true });
        });
```

Comment: Valeu Paulo, com a sua configuração e a verificação que fiz no 2-Factor Auth, funcionou. POde avaliar minha pergunta como positva? Não entendo pq a pergunta não foi clara ou não teve esforço de pesquisa..

Answer (score 0):

O problema que está a apresentar pode ter 2 causas:

- A constante `SMTP_CONFIG` pode estar a funcionar mal.
- A sua conta google tem 2-Factor Auth ativada.

Eu testei o seu código com as minhas credenciais (substituindo a variável referida anteriormente por constante globais) e ele funciona. Por isso, acredito que seja um dos problemas referidos anteriormente.

Comment: Valeu Eduardo.. Verifiquei o 2-Factor Auth e estava habilitado.. POde classificar minha pergunta como positiva.. Muitos devem ter este tipo de dúvida / problema.

Comment: Ora essa. Só um reparo, não selecionou esta resposta como correta e penso que o ajudei. Sobre a sua pergunta, eu achei a mesma clara. Continuação de bom trabalho!